# Can't boot or install from stick

Tags: system-installation

First of all, im sry if im violating any rules of this forum.

Anyway, let's get to my question. Since a couple of days im trying to install Ubuntu on my ASUS ROG Laptop. I try this via a bootable stick i made.I select the stick in the BIOS and boot from it afterwards. I am able to choose if I want to install oder Live Boot it. When im trying to live boot ( or normal install -> same result)) it, i get stuck on the purple Ubuntu screen (where the dots are). This screen is immediately after the screen where i chose to do a live boot (or normal install).

I have already tried LinuxLiveUSB, Rufus and a couple of other tools. Also i have tried multiple USB Sticks. Everytime the same result. But sometimes it reaches one dot more or less. (Dots from the loading screen). I've also tried every single USB Port.

Thank you already for your answers!
 - Juzou [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlNxo.jpg)
Version i tried: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and some older ones.

Comment: Depending on the quality/speed of the stick, it might take a while for the installation to start. Maybe try again and leave it for some time. Also, you can press one of the cursor keys to hide the splash screen and see what happens. Maybe it gives some info about what the installer is doing. It might just wait for a hardware time-out.

Good luck!

Comment: @E.F. Nijboer ty for your help!

Comment: m.imgur.com/ywmH1Ta thats The whole output

Answer (score 0):

I seriously did Not change much and suddenly it worked.
Thanks for The Reply!
-- Closed --

EDIT: Maybe adding "Nomodeset" to grub Made it work. I dont know for Sure.